# How to make a function sleep for period of seconds to prevent timeout

Tags: php

I have a code that takes sometime to finish because it checks my database
so, i need to make this function to sleep to prevent timeout
I used the following function but it didn't work and the browser keep loading then hit timeout, I am using `set_time_limit(0);` too but it didn't help

```
    foreach( $lines as $line ) {
        sleep(5); 
        do stuff here
        echo "start again";
}
```

What I need exactly is, make the browser stop loading for 5 seconds after first `foreach` success then continue the job.

Comment: Your code is making the server job take longer.  What you would be better off doing is looking at the database access and trying to ensure that it is as optimised as possible.

Comment: why do you want to use sleep function ? Basically you need to use something like promise, which will start only after first task is completed

Comment: what is promise and how to use it? Thanks @Niklesh Raut

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood how sleep function works, it won't stop loading the browser, it will wait for 5 seconds for example, on the server side, then will send response to web client. For async calls use AJAX.

If you script timeouts, try to increase max execution time.

```
  ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
```

Comment: thanks for explanation but how to reach my target in the post

Comment: try to increase max execution time, updated my answer with code.

Comment: I am using unlimited timeout in php set_time_limit(0);

Comment: try to remove sleep(), it will only increase execution time.

Comment: There is no message, the browser keep busy and loading of the long php code function results then the browser show me an error of cloudflare of timeout and after 2 or minutes i can't access the php url again but i think the function still working at the background

Comment: No its not because the function read from a txt file that has more than 400 lines and each line to be finish needs at least 10 seconds, thats why i need to the function to stop the browser and start again when each line finish @ Vladimir Štus